# How to pronounce "I'll say"

Tags: pronunciation

When pronouncing the expression **"I'll say"**, on which word I should put the emphasis?

Comment: It would help if you provided some context here. If I was feeling sarcastic or indignant or surprised, I might change my emphasis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the idiomatic phrase "*I'll say*" meaning *"I agree"*, the emphasis is on *I'll*, with an elongated vowel sound.

Note that this is not the case for *I'll say* when not used as part of the idiomatic expression meaning *I agree*. For example "*I'll say I love you*" has no such stress on the word *I'll*.

Comment: It all depends on the context.  If it followed immediately after, "Nobody will say they love me." then it *would* have the stress on *I'll*

Comment: @Jim: I don't understand what you mean. If person A says "Nobody will say they love me" and person B says (in frankly an unkind and sarcastic way) "I'll say!" meaning "I agree", then they will stress the vowel in "I'll", as stated by my first paragraph. If on the other hand they are saying "I'll say (I love you)" without stressing the vowel sound, then they aren't saying the idiomatic phrase "I'll say" meaning I agree, i.e. exactly what my second paragraph says.

Comment: @Matt: I think Jim means that person B says, "**I'll** say [I love you]!" (in other words, "Maybe nobody else will say it, but I will!"). In that case, the emphasis does shift to the _I'll_. Sort of like, "Nobody will go." "Wait! **I'll** go..."